# Form_for with checkboxes, routing and param passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0

View:

```
<% @tasks_today.each do |task| %>
  <%= form_for(task, :remote => true, :url => { :method => "patch", :action =>"update_status" }) do |f| %>
    <%= check_box_tag :task, "yes", "no", {:class => 'checkable'} %>
    <%= task.title =%>
    <%= link_to 'Not Today', remove_from_today_path(task), method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Route:

```
post 'tasks/update_status' => 'tasks#update_status', via: :patch
match 'tasks/update_status' => 'tasks#update_status', via: :patch
```

Model:

```
def update_status
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @status = Status.find_by name: params[:status]
  @task.update_status(@status)

  load
  render 'index'
end

def update
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  if @task.update(params[:task].permit(:title, :text))
    redirect_to tasks_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery -> 
  $('.checkable').on 'change', ->
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
```

Server:

```
Started PATCH "/tasks/update_status?method=patch" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-02 19:29:50 -0400
Processing by TasksController#update as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "method"=>"patch", "id"=>"update_status"}
Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "update_status"]]
```

I have two questions:

**[1]** Why is this patching to "update" and not "update_status"?

**[2]** How can I pass the task id when the checkbox is ticked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a route `PATCH /tasks/:id`, which has the effect that `update_status` is treated as the id of the task. Your routes should look like this:

```
resources :tasks do
  patch :update_status, on: :member
end
```

and in your view

```
form_for(task, url: update_status_task_path(task), method: :patch, remote: true)
```